# Incorrect GPS location reported by Google maps in Genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, genymotion

I'm using the Genymotion emulator to test my android application that needs location with GPS.

When I launch the Google Maps application, it gives me an incorrect location. Anyone have any idea about that?

Answer (score 5):

There is several solutions for your problem:

- You can choose the GPS position of a Genymotion emulator thanks to the GPS widget on the right side of the screen.

[image: Genymotion GPS icon]

[image: Genymotion GPS widget]

- You can also do it by shell commmand, look at [the documentation here](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse9)
- Or, if you have a pro license, you can do it by [the Java API](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/api/) (for unit test for example).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the second one, because the first give me the same thing

Comment: Is there a way to stop it broadcasting? It seems that even when I turn it off my app still receives the locations...

Comment: Anyone know a way to keep the GPS coordinates stored so it doesn't have to be re-enabled everytime the virtual device is launched?

Comment: It should arrive soon

Answer (score 1):

You need both the GPS on in Genymotion (where you can set the location it reports to the device as above) PLUS you need to turn on location services on the virtual device itself (under Settings/Location Services for 4.1.1 - may vary a little depending on which version of Android you are emulating).