# Mixed Geolocator and forms.maps xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, maps, xamarin.forms

I need a simple code that give the GPS location and translates it to an address.

I have found a Geolocator library and Forms.Maps and I am mixing both. Everything seems OK, except until I actually want to get the address from the coordinates. The label never receives the address.

Here is the code

```
public partial class PublicarCarona : ContentPage
{
    Geocoder geoCoder;

    public PublicarCarona()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        geoCoder = new Geocoder();
    }

    public async void OnReverseGeocodeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
            double? latitude = Convert.ToDouble (position.Latitude);
            double? longitude = Convert.ToDouble (position.Longitude);

            if (latitude != null && longitude != null)
            {
                var revposition = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(latitude.Value, longitude.Value);
                var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(revposition);
                foreach (var address in possibleAddresses)
                    lblcoordenadas.Text += address + "\n";
            }
            else lblcoordenadas.Text += "erro";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Unable to get GPS Location " + ex, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You write "`lblcoordenadas.Text doesn't return nothing`". That is a double negative, which means everything is ok.

Comment: What are you testing this on? Android or iOS Device?

Comment: Android....
No, in lblcoordenadas.text had to receive the address name and show, but the address is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the label text doesn't change this means the geoCoder isn't able to find any address and `possibleAddresses` is empty.

Note that in Android your app needs `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions. If you are target api level 23 (Android Marshmallow) you need to request those permissions at runtime. You can use [Permissions Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions) for requesting the permissions at runtime.

On iOS you need to add `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` key to the Info.plist file.

See Platform Setup section in this blog post: [Geolocation for iOS, Android, and Windows Made Easy](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/)

Comment: Thanks,,,i am testing in droid.
I putted the codes, but still not working... i got the Maps Api Key, but i don´t know whrere

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes: You don't need Maps api key. What is you Android project Target SDK ?  Did you add the permissions to AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes, i added.... look above the code..
The maps api is just when i need to show the map?

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes: What Target SDK do you have selected in Android project?

Comment: I´he tested api 16 and 23... is this what do u asked?

Comment: iam using emulator Genymotion

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes: You need to set location in Genymotion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23444055/239438

Comment: The problem is in geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(revposition) ... i can get the latitude.value and longitude.value , but in this function, return null the variable address ...

Comment: So, the error was simple. The Genymoton doesnt works with the Google services...because of this cannot get address converting the position. I tried using my phone and not emulating, and worked.
Thanks

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes: You should post it as an answer so that it's useful for other users too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="AppCaronaSurf">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBoxE8NxaTEl52vOo6l-MJiZN806XOaNsM" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />   
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```